# Explain this terminal command please

Tags: 12.04, mount, gnome-terminal

Can someone please explain the following terminal command in Ubuntu:-

```
mount -o rw, remount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-o` means "options will follow"

`rw` mounts read and write

`remount`, well, remount an already mounted system

this command won't work though as you need to provide more details regarding device filesystem, etc.

check `man mount`

Comment: Also, it will fail because of the space between "rw, " and "remount". It will give an error "mount: special device remount does not exist".